# Android OnItemClick Event does not work in GridView whit WebView and Text

Tags: android, gridview, webview, onitemclick

I have a problem because I can not capture the OnItemClick event in GridView (the item has a TextView and WebView). I load the data in GridView correctly but the onItemClick does not work Here is my code:

list_item_layout_redes.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/estilocasilla" >

<com.mhp.desarrollo.laycosandroid.CuadroImagenRed ======THIS IS A CLASS THAT EXTENDS   WEBVIEW
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

activity_redes.xml

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    .....

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gvRedes1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grisMedio"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" >
            </GridView>
        ...
</FrameLayout>
```

and this part of code is in Activity and has onItemClick part

```
if (gvRedes1 != null) {
            gvRedes1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                        long id)
```

Somebody can I help me? I do not find a solution.

Best regards
{

Comment: Probably because you are covering the whole item with your WebView. Try setting an OnClickListener on the whole view instead for each item in your getView() method

Comment: Thanks Carnal, Now I can see the item of GridView is selected, but the even onItemClick  is still not working. Can you helpe? Regards

Comment: You can just set OnClick not OnItemClick to each "view" in your getView() method for each inflated item. Then inside the onClick, you can do what you normally would do in onItemClick... since you have the position in getView() you know which item you clicked on!

Comment: Thanks Carnal, I understand your idea but I want to process the position in another Activity not in Adapter. I know that it is possible defining static methods in Activity, but this is not good for mi app. Any suggestion?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean. Process the position in another Activity? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to detect onItemOnClick in Activity not in Adapter.

Comment: Do you have adapter and activity in same class?

Comment: If you have them in same class, then there is no problem with what I told you. If not, then you need to create an interface in the activity (listener) and set it to your adapter, and in the adapter call that listener when you do something, and the result will come back to the activity.

Comment: Hi Carnal. I have not them in same class. I am going to develop the second option. Can you give me an example or link with a similar code? I hope that your suggestion work for me. Thanks. Regards

Comment: Check my answer mate, I posted a concrete answer for you in order to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` create the following `Listener`:

```
public interface GridListener{

    public void onItemClicked(int position);

}

private GridListener gridListener = new XMPPConnectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position) {

    }
};
```

Then in your `Activity` you add this `Listener` to your adapter in such a way like:

```
gvRedes1.setOnGridListener(gridListener);
```

You will need to create the method `setOnGridListener` in your adapter which takes this listener created above as input, and set the input to your instance class `GridListener` which you have in your adapter class. Something like:

```
private GridListener gridListener;
public void setOnGridListener(GridListener listener){
    gridListener = listener;
}
```

Now in your adapter when you click on an item by either using `onClick` in `getView()` like I suggested, you can make a callback with this listener to your `Activity`:

```
gridListener.onItemClicked(position);
```